# CSS/JavaScript table rows/data show and hide doesn't work with my data table.?

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried to integrate a code snippet into a data table page with some success. Only the CSS/JavaScript table rows/data show and hide doesn't work with my data table. lost for ideas, but would like to keep mark.js highlighting in the mix which works fine.

```js
var input, table, rows, markInstance;

window.onload = function init() {
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  markInstance = new Mark(table);

  clear();
}

function ContactsearchFX() {

  clear();

  if (input.value.length == 0) return;

  filterRows(input.value);
  highlightMatches(input.value);
}

function clear() {
  markInstance.unmark();

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function filterRows(text) {
  var part = text.toUpperCase();

  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var td = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

    if (td) {
      // part = GI
      // innerHtml = <MARK DATA-MARKJS="TRUE">G</MARK>ITHUB (wont match)
      // innerText = GITHUB (will match)
      var content = td.innerText.toUpperCase();

      if (content.includes(part)) {
        row.style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}

function highlightMatches(text) {
  markInstance.mark(text);
}
```

```css
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.hints {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

#myInput:invalid~.hints {
  display: block;
}

mark {
  background: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.js"></script>

<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
        Search Titles: 
        <input id="myInput" type="text" required 
               onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()" 
               placeholder="Search Titles" />
    
        <span class="hints">
          Hints: type "title", "details"...
        </span>
      </label>
</div>

<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr> -+- THIS IS WHERE I INSERT MY DATA TABLE -+-
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide full working code with also content of table

Comment: <table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="filterTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" IsIncluded="True" AsyncRefresh="True" FrameType="None" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" ViewFlag="8" Title="" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" __markuptype="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{12DD0D53-3022-4A57-8447-A964D6D28837}" id="g_12dd0d53_3022_4a57_8447_a964d6d28837" pagesize="10">
 <DataSources>
  <SharePoint:XmlUrlDataSource runat="server"

Comment: Too much code to display. Does this bit help any Alessio?

Comment: Welcome Outtheresomewhere, If I undertood you well, you want to highlight text in the table based on what you are typing, don't you?

Comment: Yes Gengns, thats the kind of point Im at - mark.js handles that part OK. The problem I have is with showing and hiding and displaying the filtered data table info, not sure if it is a CSS problem or a JavaScript problem. What more info can I provide?

Comment: Hi shrys, what is it exactly that you have edited?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, you can hide that with simple CSS classes like follows:

**HTML**

```
<input placeholder="Type title">
<table>
  <tr class="hide">
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hide">
    <td>Aladdin</td>
    <td>Nice</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hide">
    <td>Inception</td>
    <td>Cool</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hide">
    <td>Fight Club</td>
    <td>Great</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
// Selectors
const $input = document.querySelector('input')
const $heads = document.querySelector('tr:first-of-type')
const $titles = document.querySelectorAll('td:first-of-type')


$input.oninput = () => {
  // Num titles shown
  let num = 0
  // Find titles and show rows
  $titles.forEach($t => {
    const found = $input.value && 
      $t.textContent.toUpperCase().includes($input.value.toUpperCase())

    $t.parentElement.className =  found ? '' : 'hide'
    if (found) num++  
  })
  // Show header
  $heads.className = num ? '': 'hide'
}
```

Here you can check a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/0antxeum/

Hope this help or at least point you to the right direction : )

Comment: In the right direction, indeed thanks Gengns. Only need mark.js in the mix?